# Word that means something despised, strongly avoided, or strongly disliked?

Tags: nouns, objects

I know of many words that explain this feeling (abhorrence, enmity, etc for stronger examples) but what is a word that would be the object of these? As in, what word could be used as an object that was despised?

Thanks

Comment: A word request will, if you’re not careful, attract a long list of answers because it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 1):

[Anathema](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anathema)

> 1. Something or someone that one vehemently dislikes.

Answer (score 1):

[*Bête noire*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/b%C3%AAte%20noire), while not one word, means just what you described:

> *noun*
>
> : a person or thing strongly detested or avoided; [bugbear](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bugbear)